# Multi-level Controller

Tags: codeigniter

i have problem with viewing page within sub-subfolder. when i access the url it says page not found.
The url i used to access is **localhost/amc/program/admin/user** 
Here is the folder structure i have:

**controller**
-program
     --admin
        *user.php*

**core**
-program
     --admin
        *admin_controller.php*

**models**
-program
     --admin
        *user_model.php*

**views**
-program
     --admin
        *user_list.php*

And here's the controller code

```
<?php
class User extends Admin_Controller
{
    public $data = array(
        'halaman' => 'user',
        'main_view' => 'program/admin/user_list',
        'title' => 'Data User',
    );

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('program/admin/User_model', 'user_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $user = $this->user_model->get_all_user_data();
        if ($user) {
            $this->data['userData'] = $user;
        } else {
            $this->data['userData'] = 'Tidak ada data user.';
        }
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
    }
}
```

thank's for your attention guys

Comment: Files need to be Capital first (i.e `User.php` or `Admin_controller.php`). Does it work when you access `localhost/amc/index.php/program/admin/user`?

Comment: I changed the file name, and still doesn't work. And it doesn't work too with accessing localhost/amc/index.php/program/admin/user

Comment: I just found out that codeigniter doesn't support multi-level subfolder controller. But there's a custom router that i found [Here](https://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/). I will try that and post here if its work

Comment: Right. That could work, altough need to be checked for core directory too. If failed, all files need to be in core directly.

Comment: Actually the extension that work for my CI version is here: [multi-level sub-folder controller](https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-multi-level-controller-extension/blob/master/core/MY_Router.php). Thanks for your attention Tpojka, very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that CI doesnt support multi-level sub-folder controller, but there's work around that enable us to do that.
I found this code that enable multi-level sub-folder controller:
[multi-level controller](https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-multi-level-controller-extension/blob/master/core/MY_Router.php)

credit: https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-multi-level-controller-extension/blob/master/core/MY_Router.php